# CSS float right not working with Firefox and image resized

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've the following html code that show 1 image on left, then a text box in the middle, and an image on the right. The two images have the same size and  resized to take the whole height of the screen.

This work fine on IE, Chrome but on FireFox 15, ..., 27 the image isn't completely on the right, ther is an important margin. 
The images are 760x1660 and the screen has less heigh thant 1660 then it's resized.
The image appear as if the image had a margin coresponding to the original with (760px) minus the resized width...

Any idea to solve this for FireFox using css?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .left {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
        height: 100%;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .content {
    }


</style>


<img class="left" src="./left.jpg" />
<img class="right" src="./right.jpg" />

<div class="content">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
</div>
```

You can see the unwanted space on this picture http://postimg.org/image/80y7aar41/
It works fine on JSFiddle but when you put the code in a page http://www.filedropper.com/t4_1 and then resize the browser you'll see the unwated space

Comment: please provide a fiddle with sample images

Comment: I've set up a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjhbV/), but you need to explain more what the problem is. This looks the same in both FF/Chrome

Answer (score 0):

See my fiddle for example, it works with mine firefox and chrome

http://fiddle.jshell.net/S6qXk/4/

Don't set for a class something 100%
That is the problem you have.

Comment: It work on jsfidle but not on a page by itself. I've change your code with some images that I found on the net and that are more representative of what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` in the .right and .left classes.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is right in front of you ;)

just change the width of your "body tag"

```
body {
    width: 100%; /*change it to 99% - and everything seems to run just fine in all my browsers, IE, Firefox, opera, chrome*/
}
```

Comment: Sorry but in doesn't work on mine... You can download the exemple that I aded and change the widht...
Why shouldn't I have a widht of 100%???

Comment: when u have a width of 100% browser such as opera, seem to cut into the right image...
are you also trying to get the same white space on both sides of the browser window?

Comment: I'd like to have no white space at all...
This space appear only on the right side

Comment: im gonna leave another comment with another full answer

Answer (score 0):

css
     body {

```
    width: 99%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.right {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
#left_image {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width:15%;
}
#right_image {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width:15%;
}
#center_div {   
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:left;
    width:68%;
    padding:15;
}
```

html:

```
 <div id="left_image"><img class="left" src="http://www.hellopro.fr/images/produit-2/0/2/0/pompe-a-entrainement-magnetique-verticale-non-metallique-334020.jpg" /></div>
 <div id="right_image"><img class="right" src="http://www.hellopro.fr/images/produit-2/0/2/0/pompe-a-entrainement-magnetique-verticale-non-metallique-334020.jpg" /></div>

 <div id="center_div">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
    </div>
```

Comment: if you want to get rid of all the white space on left and right u can now adjust your body % back to 100% instead of 99%